# Paypal Adaptive Payments remove memo option?

Tags: paypal

I've set up my site to use paypal adaptive payments, while testing, when going to submit a payment, after logging into paypal account on the paypal page there is an option:

Send a note to your customers about this payment.
And then the user can enter a memo. This memo can be set via the API as well if I don't want the user to enter it.

However, I want to remove this field entirely as I don't really need it, but mainly because "Send a note to your customers about this payment" doesn't make sense since the person paying is the buyer so they are the 'customer' (on my site no one is actually the customer since its a gift rather than a purchase, but regardless it doesn't make sense).

So is there a way to completely remove the memo section, or to at least remove/change the "Send a note to your customers about this payment." text?

Comment: Did you find a way? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer from PayPal support:

> I understand you would like the Memo area removed however this is a
>   mandatory field that we've been instructed we have to have when we
>   were successful in gaining our licence to operate and removing this is
>   not an option.